# Visual Studio 2015 : switch between remote compilation (on Raspberry) and local compilation (on Windows)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio-2015, cross-compiling

I have a project that I want to run and test on my local Windows machine, but that I want to deploy on a Raspberry.

I managed to set up the "Visual C++ for Linux Development" extension. I created a new solution, using "New Solution>Visual C++>cross-platform>Linux".

It works well, I can compile my code on the Raspberry.

However, I would like to easily switch between this remote linux target to a windows target, while sharing the same source code.

What can I do to achieve this?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two projects in your VS solution, one for Linux and another for Windows. You can share the source between projects so, once you have created the first project, create the second for the other platform as an empty project and drag'n drop the source across. You'll likely want to bracket platform specific code in `#if def`s (e.g. test for  `WIN32`).

BTW: if you're still using VS2015 you are some way behind the current VCLinux version.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I did in the end! I created two projects under the same solution, with the same sources, and I modified my sources with `#ifndef __arm__` clauses for the things that I could not run on the Raspberry. Thanks for the help :)